# Android Progress Bar not working

Tags: java, android

I have made a progress bar in Android but it is not at all working. What am I doing wrong? I have just started to learn android. Below is my code.

MainActivity.java-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    int mporgress=0;
    EditText time;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
           public void Startbuttononclick(View view){
               Button startbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
               startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {

                       mporgress = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
                       progressBar.setProgress(mporgress);

                       new Thread(new Runnable() {
                           public void run() {
                               while (mporgress < 100) {
                                   // Update the progress bar
                                   mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                       public void run() {
                                           progressBar.setProgress(mporgress);
                                           mporgress = doWork();
                                           try{
                                               Thread.sleep(1000);
                                           }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                                       }
                                   });
                               }
                           }
                       }).start();

                   }
               });
           }
    public void doprogress(View view) {

    }
        public int doWork(){
                  mporgress++;
            return mporgress;
        }
}
```

Activity_main.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.android.progressbar.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter the time:"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scrollbarSize="500dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="START"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="Startbuttononclick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Check out this image below-
 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TBIb.png

Note- Enter the time in this image is an EditText with a hint and not a TextView.

It is appearing but not working.

I have done these changes so far.-
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/UujpB.png

But still the progress bar is still continuously rotating.

Comment: Define "not at all working".  Not displaying at all?  Not updating?  Something else entirely?

Comment: @GabeSechan i have updated the question. Please review it.

Comment: I think, its because you are calling sleep on MainThread. Try moving sleep call to outer thread.

Comment: @Knattic,check answer man

Comment: Doesn't work. The progress bar is just rotating. Continuously

Comment: where did u init. the edittext before ?

Comment: No where is guess but even after initializing it is happening.

Comment: @Knattic, check for updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you forgot to initialize `EditText -time` and `ProgressBar`. Init it inside `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
    time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); //here
}
```

Also inside button click the `bar`:

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
mporgress = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
    ................
          .............
```

Comment: The app is still crashing. And below is the log- java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Knattic You need to initialize every view via findViewById.  They don't magically fill in when you call setContentView.

Comment: Yeah sorry i forgot to do that.

Comment: @Knattic, what do u want to do with progressBar, tell?

Comment: I want the progress bar to complete a full rotation under the specific time the user has specified.